# Check Checkbox at Certain Stage

Tags: validation-rule

I need to ensure that when the stage is changing from Stage 1 to Stage 2, the checkbox is checked.
Stage 1 = "1 - Qualify"
Stage 2 = "2 - Consideration"

Name of checkbox: Demo_Completed

I created:

```
AND(
    ISPICKVALUE(stagename "2-Consideration"), 
    ISBLANK(Demo_Completed_c)
)))
```

but is not working

Comment: syntax errors in the formula aside (there are multiple syntax errors), what does "not working" mean. You need to be very specific and detailed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a formula field. You're referencing the field itself in the formula. The current formula is saying that the field will can only be true when the field is false.

At least that's what I'm assuming you're trying to do because I'm also assuming Demo_completed__c is a checkbox, so you can't use isBlank(). You can just check if it's false with = FALSE.

If you just want the Demo_Completed__c checkbox checked when the stage is past the first stage, and that's the first stage, you may as well make the formula

NOT(ISPICKVALUE(stagename,"1 - Qualify"))

Then it'll be checked when it's not the first stage.

Comment: This is supposed to be a validation rule (as indicated in the question tags)

Comment: Ah ok I see what you're saying I think. In that case, try switching out isBlank since it's a checkbox field and there should be a comma between stagename and the name in the ISPICKVAL

Comment: @PeterLuo Just so you know Derek, who commented to your answer, didn't actually ask this question, he's merely trying to clarify the question for you.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the clarification, to both of you haha